# passwd source code

Tags: root, c, passwd, setuid, uid

I am trying to look at [the source code of the passwd and gpasswd programs](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/passwd.c). These tools check the effective UID set to zero to complete execution successfully. But I am a noob to C and couldn't find the line of code that checks if the process is being run by UID == 0. I would appreciate any hints or solutions.

Answer (score 5):

If you’re referring to the “shadow-utils” implementations of `passwd`, you’ll find the test [here](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/58b6e97a9eef866e9e479fb781aaaf59fb11ef36/src/passwd.c#L739):

```c
    /*
     * The program behaves differently when executed by root than when
     * executed by a normal user.
     */
    amroot = (getuid () == 0);
```

In `gpasswd`, the test is defined in two phases; first [the UID is stored](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/58b6e97a9eef866e9e479fb781aaaf59fb11ef36/src/gpasswd.c#L960):

```c
    /*
     * Make a note of whether or not this command was invoked by root.
     * This will be used to bypass certain checks later on. Also, set
     * the real user ID to match the effective user ID. This will
     * prevent the invoker from issuing signals which would interfere
     * with this command.
     */
    bywho = getuid ();
```

then that’s used in [the `amroot` macro](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/58b6e97a9eef866e9e479fb781aaaf59fb11ef36/src/gpasswd.c#L67):

```c
/* Indicate if gpasswd was called by root */
#define amroot  (0 == bywho)
```